# MySQL table with fixed number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have table `documents (id, name, time)`.  Is there a special sql command to set table limit by 10 rows?

Comment: Are you looking to limit the amount of rows in the table, or the number of rows returned by a select statement?

Comment: i need to limit amount of rows in the table

Comment: Well then see Haim's answer. It's not possible in any traditional sense.

Comment: Also can I ask why you want to do this? I'm sure there is another way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: in this table is information of saved documents name, so i'm using this table for displaying "latest 10 generated documents"

Comment: So save them all and in your select statement only show the 10 most recent. There is a time field there so I assume that this can be used for this purpose. You shouldn't have people having to look directly at the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display the "latest 10 generated documents", no need for a separate table. Just use a query on your existing table:

```
SELECT id, name, `time`
FROM documents
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

no you could not set a limit on the mysql table, you can achive this with trigger that delete rows.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR( 99 ) NOT NULL,
  `time` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

then you can use this horrible query to limit row numbers by recycling the row having the lowest `id` field:

```
INSERT INTO documents (id,name,time)
  SELECT
    IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documents) < 3 -- max row number you allow
       ,NULL -- just use autoincrement id
       ,(SELECT MIN(id) FROM documents) -- update row with smallest id
    ),
    -- your values to insert
    'name'
    ,'2011-11-11'
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id   = (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM documents) -- new id
    -- your values again, now for update
   ,name = 'name'
   ,time = '2011-11-11'
```

Somebody please confirm if this query is atomic, i think it is, but who knows…