# Limit maximum number of records/rows in Table

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

Can I limit the number of records in the table?

So if we'll reach the maximum number, MySQL will disallow new records to be inserted.

Are there some functions or techniques to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: (assuming mysql supports triggers) you can do that with a trigger...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155053/can-we-limit-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-in-mysql , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254522/mysql-table-with-fixed-number-of-rows